# Add character limit on a channel entry tag field?

Tags: channel-fields

I want to add a character limit on the display portion of expression engines channel field, not on the back end entry.

for example, If i have a field "Description" I want to be able to display a "preview" of it, at 50 characters, and then if clicked, or on another page, I want to show that same field, but with no character limit to display the full text.

Answer (score 2):

there are loads of character limit/string manipulation plugins here https://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=character+limit&addon_version_support=ee2

Comment: and Ellis Lab provides a first party plugin as well. https://github.com/EllisLab/Char-Limit/releases

Comment: TruncHTML gets my vote - especially the way it can handle truncating html without leaving orphaned html tags.

Comment: I was hoping there was something built in that I just missed in the documentation, but TrunchHTML will get the job done.
Thanks!